# How do I populate matrix with a vector, considering Matrix as chart and vector as line

Tags: matlab

Consider following values

```
result=zeros(11,11);
line=(4:0.4:8);
```

Imagine result as a 11x11 X-Y chart paper. So initially we have a blank chart paper. As in a chart plot, I want to populate values of line in result matrix so that we get an upward sloping line when we display matrix.

Consider following figure which I want as result.

[image]

Here, result matrix can be visualized as chart paper with origin at bottom left corner. Now, for X=1, line(1)=4; for X=2, line(2)=4.4,.. and so on.

I have written following code which serves the purpose.

```
result=zeros(11,11);
line=(4:0.4:8);

for i=1:length(line)
    temp=floor(line(i));
    result(length(line)-temp+1,i)=line(i);
end
```

Is there a more efficient way to implement this solution? (I shall be working with 20000x20000 matrix, so method needs to be fast)

As suggested in comments, Problem Description is as follows:

I have lets say 1000 lines. All of these lines have different slopes and intercept. I know the x range of the lines and y range of the lines. There is not much I can infer from data if I plot these lines simultaneously on a single plot. The resulting image will be something like this:

[image]

Not much can be inferred about this plot. However, if I can get this information saved in a big matrix, then I can analyse where maximum lines are passing through at a particular X index and make further analysis accordingly.

**Further Details**

I am discretinizing Y axis into 1000 equally spaced interval:
sample code as follows:

```
range=max(data)-min(data);
percent=0.20;
outerRange= max(data)+range*percent - (min(data)-range*percent);
outerRangeValues=min(data)-range*percent:outerRange/1000:max(data)+range*percent;
```

Even though it is entirely possible that a particularly steep line will pass through 2 or more rows in a single column, I'll only select only one of the rows to be filled by line in a single column. This can be done by taking average of rows values for a particular column and assigning single row to be its value for that column

Comment: This reads as a perfect example of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Could you describe why do you want this? What is the application that leads you to think this is a solution to your problem?

Comment: Your edit makes clear that you are using a feather to fix a screw, or in other words, you are using the completely wrong tool to fix your problem

Comment: @AnderBiguri Please suggest a more appropriate solution for what I am trying to do

Comment: Before I can suggest: You seem to be discretizing your domain. How do you define that discretization? is the heigh/width of those matrix elements arbitrary? In your example is 11x11. Why? Also, you defined the intersection with rounding, but in reality, your lines may cross more than 1 column on your matrix, right?

Comment: @AnderBiguri Further details entered in problem description regarding discretization and how I plan to handle when my lines cross more than 1 rows for a particular column

Comment: I suggest defining all the lines in a parametric way, , evaluating all of them on  the same `x` values, and binning the `y` results. Then a simple addition should give you the desired result.  This is not far from what you have already. If I have mroe time I will answer the question, otherwise anyone: feel free to answer it with this idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`sub2ind`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) to keep things vectorized and avoid loops.

The idea is to find all the row and column indices which will have to be modified.

For `X` axis it is easy, it is simply one per column so the `X` indices will be `1,2,3,...,np`.

For the `Y` axis, you have to bin the `line` values into the `Y` grid. Since indices have to be integers, you have to convert your floating point values into integers. For that you can choose between `round`, `floor` and `ceil`. Each will place some values slightly differently, it is up to you to define which rounding method makes sense for your problem.

Once you have your indices `[row_indices,column_indices]`, you convert them to linear indices into the matrix by using `sub2ind`, then you assign the values of `line` into these linear indices.

In code:

```
line=(4:0.4:8);                     % your input (line vector)

np = numel(line) ;                  % determine size of matrix/chart

% identify column and row indices to modify
idCol = 1:np ;
idRow = fliplr( round( line ) ) ;   % choose "round", "floor" or "ceil"

% build the result
result              = zeros(np);
linearInd           = sub2ind( [np,np], idRow, idCol ) ;
result(linearInd)   = line ;
```

Gives you:

```
>> result
result =
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   7.2 7.6 8
0   0   0   0   0   0   6.4 6.8 0   0   0
0   0   0   5.2 5.6 6   0   0   0   0   0
0   4.4 4.8 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: @Dev-iL. ha ha ...by just a few seconds, I saw yours the second after I posted.

Comment: This is, in essence, what the Bresenham line drawing algorithm does.